# Accessing a server from node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a js file with the following code

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
   res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
   res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8000, '127.0.0.1');

console.log('Server running');
```

Now, if I access the go to browser by `127.0.0.1:8000` its perfectly fine, but I want to access SERVER using its IP, but when I modify my code for server IP and execute code an  error occurs. Can someone explain why I am unable to access it?

Comment: "*If I go to the browser by `127.0.0.1:8000` it's perfectly fine, but I want to access SERVER using IP*" - that's exactly what you are doing, using a hostname would be `localhost:8000`. Think you need to explain a bit more exactly what you mean by "using it's IP".

Answer (score 0):

You need to omit the second argument to the `listen` method to allow access on any IP:

```
}).listen(8000);
```

see [the documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback) for more details